# Сборка приложения на pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

При сборке приложения на macOS выполняю команду

pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py

```
63 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
63 INFO: Python: 3.9.1
73 INFO: Platform: macOS-10.15.7-x86_64-i386-64bit
74 INFO: wrote /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/main.spec
77 INFO: UPX is not available.
79 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/Rita/Desktop/main', '/Users/Rita/Desktop/main']
85 INFO: checking Analysis
85 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
85 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
88 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
95 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
99 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3561 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
3562 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9'
6223 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6430 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6438 INFO: Analyzing /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/main.py
6641 INFO: Processing module hooks...
6642 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
6818 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
6819 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
6820 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
6846 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7005 INFO: checking Tree
7005 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
7005 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
7030 INFO: checking Tree
7030 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
7030 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
7119 INFO: checking Tree
7119 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
7119 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
7123 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7203 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7206 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7240 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.Qt.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7258 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtMultimedia.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7304 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7306 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSql.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7362 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtQml.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7493 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7494 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtQuickWidgets.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7578 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7579 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7654 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7655 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7664 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtNetwork.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7684 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7737 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtTest.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7795 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7795 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7805 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7864 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtXml.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7883 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSerialPort.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7912 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtHelp.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
7990 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtQuick.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
8048 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSensors.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
8078 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtOpenGL.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
8155 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
8229 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8266 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8270 INFO: Including run-time hook '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
8274 INFO: Including run-time hook '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
8281 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DInput.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DInput (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DQuickScene2D.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DQuickScene2D (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./QtGamepad.framework/Versions/5/QtGamepad (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DCore.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DCore (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DRender.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DRender (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8409 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DQuick.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DQuick (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8410 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DLogic.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DLogic (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene2D/libqtquickscene2dplugin.dylib)
8455 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DAnimation.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DAnimation (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8456 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DInput.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DInput (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8456 ERROR: Can not find path ./QtGamepad.framework/Versions/5/QtGamepad (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8456 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DCore.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DCore (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8456 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DRender.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DRender (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8456 ERROR: Can not find path ./Qt3DLogic.framework/Versions/5/Qt3DLogic (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtQuick/Scene3D/libqtquickscene3dplugin.dylib)
8600 ERROR: Can not find path ./QtMultimediaQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaQuick (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/qml/QtMultimedia/libdeclarative_multimedia.dylib)
9048 INFO: Looking for eggs
9048 INFO: Using Python library /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
9052 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/build/main/warn-main.txt
9097 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/build/main/xref-main.html
9175 INFO: checking PYZ
9175 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
9175 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz
9651 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/build/main/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
9667 INFO: checking PKG
9668 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
9668 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
31132 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
31196 INFO: Bootloader /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/runw
31196 INFO: checking EXE
31196 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
31196 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
31197 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/dist/main
31398 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/Rita/Desktop/main/dist/main
31402 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
31462 INFO: checking BUNDLE
31462 INFO: Building BUNDLE because BUNDLE-00.toc is non existent
31463 INFO: Building BUNDLE BUNDLE-00.toc
31662 INFO: moving BUNDLE data files to Resource directory
```

После запускаю файл и он завершается принудительно без описания ошибки

.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/Rita/Desktop/main'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='main.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Основной файл от куда запускается приложения имеет такое начало

```
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Те ошибки которые находятся в командной строке при поиске в гугле результата не дали.

Comment: установил pyinstaller через homebrew (до этого было установлен через pip) ошибки при установке пропали, но приложение все равно не работает корректно. Запускается и сразу сворачивается

Comment: Так происходит с любым приложением, даже самым простым или только с одним конкретным, о котором вы сейчас пишите ?

Comment: так происходит с любым приложением, когда открываю консоль в папке dist то в консоле надпись ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
[11778] Failed to execute script main